# Can't create grid rows dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to dynamically add rows to WPF grid. The first row of the grid is defined in xaml.
My view model has a property of collection. Number of the other dynamically added grid rows must be equal to the count of items in the collection.
I checked that collection is not empty and parameter "count" of the collection is adequate (passed it to the view control). UserControl Tag takes collection count parameter at the moment of usercontrol creating.

Why it doesn't work?

ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel 
        
    public List<DateTime> WorkTimeRow { get; private set; }
    public int RowCount { get { return WorkTimeRow.Count; } }        
    
   ...
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl ...>
<Grid x:Name="gSchedule" ShowGridLines="True" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>            
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

XAML.CS:

```
public SimpleScheduleControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInitialized(e);            
        
            for (int n = 0; n == Convert.ToInt32(Tag); n++)
            {
                RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition() { MinHeight = 50 };
                gSchedule.RowDefinitions.Add(row);                    
            }         
        
    }
```

I tried to create a collection with time intervals, pass it's count parameter to xaml.cs and create number of my grid rows I need in moment of user control initializing. I don't get any error or binding failure.
Could you help me?

Comment: Forgot to say. I get a usercontrol with a grid defined in xaml (columns and 1 row)

Comment: ViewModels shouldn't inherit from DependencyObject as this is part of the WPF visual tree. This is not really the idiomatic way of writing this code in WPF, you can achieve what you want with data bindings https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-5.0

Comment: Perhaps I should do transfer an object to view model property in another way, thanks. But I make it. Why grid rows are not building?

Comment: `n == Convert.ToInt32(Tag)` should certainly be `n < Convert.ToInt32(Tag)`. Besides that, your control should expose a dedicated integer property instead of using Tag.

Comment: Thanks you all! But I'm sure I saw here a comment about grid rendering. This comment suggested to start asynchronic method in view constructor because grid row is not a UI Elements and it needs to render grid again changes become approved in the view. It seems an author deleted it. How can I try to do it?